# How to get user id from a mention string

Tags: node.js, regex, discord

In Discord mentions are stylized as `<@USER_ID>` how do i get user id from such string using RegEx. I want to get the number in between `<@` and `>`.

I tried `(?=<@)[0-9]+(?=>)` but that's not working.

Thanks!

Comment: its missing a complete and reproducible example. Anyway. "<@1234>".match(/<@([0-9]+)>/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched 2 characters in your regex. `=<` should be `<=`
If your language supports positive lookbehinds, you could do it like this:

[`(?<=<@)\d+(?=>)`](https://regex101.com/r/yM4rmP/1)

Else you could try it like this and your digits are in the first captured group.

[`<@(\d+)>`](https://regex101.com/r/yM4rmP/2)

Comment: Sorry, positive lookbehinds are not supported in my case. /<@(\d+)>/ consumes whole string, icluding "<@" and ">"

Comment: The digits are in the first capturing group.

Comment: Oh, i got it i just never used capturing groups before. Thanks!